# SVN always asking for authentication when commiting

Tags: authentication, svn, sourceforge

I have used SVN with repository on sourceforge. I choosed https to check out Repository,It's Ok but when I tried to commit a new file to repository, SVN always asking for authentication(username and password) although I have choosen checkbox to remember my authentication. I'm sure that I've set permission for user on sourceforge repository.

Comment: There is not enough information to help you. What kind of client do you use? What is the operating system?

Comment: I using windows 8, and I'm using tortoiseSVN to check out source code